# Sublime Text 3 - Stop showing "Update to newer version!" window?

Tags: sublimetext3

I researched a bit and I found the **Stack Overflow** post with the same name, but it included some software that doesn't exist today; these posts were made like a decade ago. Anyways, I'm using an older PC with a **32-bit System!** Yes, I know it's **quite old**, but I'll get a new one pretty soon, but until then I'm gonna use this one. Every time I open Sublime, it pops an `Update` window. It's so annoying! I looked for the solution, but unfortunately, I've never found it. **I don't know whether I should've written this to StackExchange, but anyways.** **Please, don't close** this question too early, I just wanna know the answer to this problem. Thanks, anyone for replying! :)

Oh, just in case if you need my current version, it's `3.2.2, Build 3211`

Comment: Can you please link to the other SO question you're referring to?

Comment: Not sure it still works: go to preferences -> settings (User) and add “update_check”: false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you buy a license then you can switch off the automatic update check as is noted here:
https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/paid-vs-free-version-of-sublime-text/45846

There is not supposed to be another way to stop that update window.

Comment: Thanks! I'll also try implementing `"update_check": false` in the `Preferences` tab in Sublime Text 3. :)